# How do reduce count of inserts in tsql script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to fill the User's table using only one insert. There are 4 columns in the table:

```
FirstName    LastName   Password    Email
```

Now I can do it only using two inserts. First, insert FirstName and LastName and secondly, according to their names, generate Passwords and Emails. So, after first insert I have Passwords column and Email column filled up with NULL. That's why I need to delete unnecessary rows from table.
The code below:

```
DROP TABLE Users

CREATE TABLE Users(
    FirstName nvarchar(10) ,
    LastName nvarchar(10),
    Password nvarchar(128),
    Email nvarchar(30),
    )

INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Adams','Armstrong'),
                                            ('John','Barnes'),
                                            ('Mark','Barnetty'),
                                            ('Mike','Ra'),
                                            ('Harry','Radley'),
                                            ('Nick','Kade'),
                                            ('Brian','Kael'),
                                            ('Lea','Fahim'),
                                            ('Julia','Dacey'),
                                            ('Anna','Octavio'),
                                            ('Kate','Yale')

INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Password, Email) 
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Password, Email =
    CASE 
    WHEN Email = 0 THEN
    LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@hotmail.com'
    WHEN Email = 1 THEN
    LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@gmail.com'
    WHEN Email = 2 THEN
    LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@mail.ru'
    END
    FROM (SELECT  FirstName, LastName, REPLACE(LOWER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), NEWID())), '-', '') as Password,
    CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 as INT) as Email from Users) as random

DELETE FROM Users WHERE Password IS NULL and  Email IS NULL

SELECT * FROM Users
```

How does fill the Users table using only one insert? 
P.S. This table is already temp for another one.

Comment: Where do the name values come from? Are you always hard-coding them into the insert statement or are they selected from another table or data source?

Comment: So if a user gets a `hotmail.com`, `gmail.com` or `mail.ru` totally depends on change ?

Comment: why are you doing two inserts, and then deleting one of the two rows? Bizarre. Use an UPDATE to add the email/password to the _existing_ row! But if the email value comes from an input parameter (e.g. @email) you can just put the CASE statement straight into the original INSERT and use the parameter to decide what to do.

Comment: I would also suggest you look into storing passwords as a salted and hashed cipher instead of in plain text. Storing passwords in plain text is a very bad practice.

Comment: @Jacob H  hard-coding only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clean solution using `CROSS APPLY` without the need for a CTE:

```
INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Password, Email)
SELECT 
    Names.FirstName, 
    Names.LastName, 
    REPLACE(LOWER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), NEWID())), '-', ''),
    CASE 
        WHEN EmailInfo.EmailType = 0 THEN EmailInfo.EmailName + '@hotmail.com'
        WHEN EmailInfo.EmailType = 1 THEN EmailInfo.EmailName + '@gmail.com'
        WHEN EmailInfo.EmailType = 2 THEN EmailInfo.EmailName + '@mail.ru'
    END
FROM (
        VALUES 
        ('Adams','Armstrong'),
        ('John','Barnes'),
        ('Mark','Barnetty'),
        ('Mike','Ra'),
        ('Harry','Radley'),
        ('Nick','Kade'),
        ('Brian','Kael'),
        ('Lea','Fahim'),
        ('Julia','Dacey'),
        ('Anna','Octavio'),
        ('Kate','Yale')
    ) Names (FirstName, LastName)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) AS EmailName,
            CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 as INT) AS EmailType
    ) EmailInfo
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Password, Email) 
    SELECT FirstName, LastName
        , [Password] = REPLACE(LOWER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), NEWID())), '-', '')
        , Email =
                CASE CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 as INT)
                WHEN  0 THEN LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@hotmail.com'
                WHEN  1 THEN LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@gmail.com'
                WHEN  2 THEN LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@mail.ru'
                END
from (VALUES ('Adams','Armstrong'),
                                            ('John','Barnes'),
                                            ('Mark','Barnetty'),
                                            ('Mike','Ra'),
                                            ('Harry','Radley'),
                                            ('Nick','Kade'),
                                            ('Brian','Kael'),
                                            ('Lea','Fahim'),
                                            ('Julia','Dacey'),
                                            ('Anna','Octavio'),
                                            ('Kate','Yale')) a(FirstName, LastName)
```

Comment: The case for email won't work because each RAND() function will generate different values and it's possible that multiple cases may come true at the same time. Or maybe it will always be the first case and other cases won't be executed

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Of course. Edited to correct that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE

```
DROP TABLE Users

CREATE TABLE Users(
    FirstName nvarchar(10) ,
    LastName nvarchar(10),
    Password nvarchar(128),
    Email nvarchar(30),
    )


;WITH Names AS (
    SELECT U.FirstName, U.LastName FROM (
    VALUES ('Adams','Armstrong'),
            ('John','Barnes'),
            ('Mark','Barnetty'),
            ('Mike','Ra'),
            ('Harry','Radley'),
            ('Nick','Kade'),
            ('Brian','Kael'),
            ('Lea','Fahim'),
            ('Julia','Dacey'),
            ('Anna','Octavio'),
            ('Kate','Yale')
    ) AS U (FirstName, LastName)
), RandomUsers AS (
SELECT 
      FirstName
    , LastName
    , REPLACE(LOWER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), NEWID())), '-', '') as Password
    , CASE CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 as INT)
        WHEN  0 THEN
        LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@hotmail.com'
        WHEN  1 THEN
        LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@gmail.com'
        WHEN  2 THEN
        LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@mail.ru'
        END AS Email
FROM Names
)
INSERT INTO Users(FirstName, LastName, Password, Email) 
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Password, Email 
FROM RandomUsers
WHERE Password IS NOT NULL AND Email IS NOT NULL 

SELECT * FROM Users
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written your query. Try this

```
DROP TABLE Users

CREATE TABLE Users(
    FirstName nvarchar(10) ,
    LastName nvarchar(10),
    Password nvarchar(128),
    Email nvarchar(30),
    )

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT FirstName = 'Adams',LastName = 'Armstrong',Email = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 as INT),[Password] = REPLACE(LOWER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), NEWID())), '-', '')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FirstName = 'John',LastName = 'Barnes',Email = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 as INT),[Password] = REPLACE(LOWER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), NEWID())), '-', '')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FirstName = 'Mark',LastName = 'Barnetty',Email = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3 as INT),[Password] = REPLACE(LOWER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), NEWID())), '-', '')
)
INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Password, Email) 
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    [Password],
    Email =
    CASE 
        WHEN Email = 0 THEN
        LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@hotmail.com'
        WHEN Email = 1 THEN
        LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@gmail.com'
        WHEN Email = 2 THEN
        LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName) + '@mail.ru'
        END
    FROM CTE
        WHERE [Password] IS NOT NULL
            OR
            Email IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM Users
```

I've only included the first 3 records, you can add more union all for more records.

Also, I've removed the Delete statement as it is already filtered in the Where condition